# What is the purpose of HEADERS in a message

Tags: outlook

Why do we have headers in the messages? There is a button in the send and receive in 2013 that says download headers, what does it do ?

Answer (score 1):

See [What is an Email Header?](http://whatismyipaddress.com/email-header).

A lot of time is required for downloading messages with large attachments. Outlook allows you to download a small piece of emails that can you let you know what it is. So, you can decide whether you need to download it or delete without downloading and spending your time for waiting.